# Why is this .innerHTML not working?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

When I run this code, it doesn't set the `innerHTML` of `console`. The last two `alert()`s aren't working either. The `console` `id` exists, as in a later portion of the docuument, its `innerHTML` is set into another variable successfully. What errors do I have?
The parameters in the url both exist as well because the first two `alert()`s work.

```
var console = getParameterByName('consoletext');
alert(console);
var submission = getParameterByName('input');
alert(submission);
document.getElementById("console").innerHTML = console + submission;
var text = document.getElementById("console").innerHTML;
alert(text);
alert("text");
//parseInput(submission);
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

function parseInput(input) {
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your console (hit F12 on Windows or Opt + Cmd + I on Mac) for errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use `console`, as per other answer. But it should still work, there is nothing wrong with your code and it works in my browser.

Do you get any errors, like your #console element not yet being loaded?

Other than that, it might be a mistake in code or markup you did not post.

Comment: Yup, my script got moved to the beginning, before the div was loaded, this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

console is reserved syntax. Use other name for the variable.

Comment: Not true. `console` is not a reserved word and you can run `console = null` in your console right now and it will re-assign it.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't change anything. (I'm assuming due to it not being a reserved word)